# Create interface class to make a plugin architecture in VB.NET for Begginers

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on using the interface class in vb.net. I have 2 separate dll files and I would like to integrate those files into one dll file by creating an interface plugin architecture. Within the integrated files, I can choose which dll files that I want to use in other applications.

I already imported the needed dll files and created the Interface Main with the following code.  I also have created a class for implementing the interface plugin architecture. But I have some trouble understanding how to implement an interface for executing/loading the dll files.

```
Namespace Type.Interface
''' <summary>
''' Interfaces implemented by plugins
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Interface IPlugIn

    ''' <summary>
    ''' PlugIn Name
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    ReadOnly Property Name() As String 
    
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Run PlugIn
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Sub Run()

End Interface
End Namespace
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an "interface class". There are interfaces, which define a set of functionality that must be implemented, and there are classes, which can implement one or more interfaces.

Comment: You use Reflection to load the plugins. Generally speaking, you look in a specific folder for DLLs, you load each assembly and then you look for types that implement your interface. You create instances of those types and access their members via the interface. It's really too big a topic for one question here but there are undoubtedly examples on the web. If you search for ".net plugin architecture" or the like then you should be able to find code examples that perform the steps I outlined.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean when you say that you want to integrate libraries. Generally speaking, you will define the plugin interface in a library and your application will reference that library so that it knows about that interface. You make the interface library public and then other developers can reference it and create classes in their own libraries that implement the interface. They can then place their library in the plugin folder of your application and your app will run their plugin.

Comment: @John : Thank you for your advice, I already created it and it works :)